# how to see number movements in c++ boolean?

Tags: c++, boolean, boolean-expression

I have a small program to sort random numbers into the right sequence number. Well, I want to see every random number move. what should be added to it?

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void pindah (int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void tukar (int arr[], int n) {
    int i, j;
    bool trade;
    for (i=0; i < n-1; i++) {
        trade = false;
        for (j=0; j < n-i-1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
                pindah(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
                trade = true;
            }
        }
        if (trade == false)
            break;
    }
}

void cetakArray (int arr[], int n) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " "; //tampil data
    }
}

int main () {
    int arr[] = {4, 6, 7, 2, 1, 5, 8, 10, 9, 3};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int); //menghitung jumlah data array
    cout << "setelah diurutkan : \n";
    tukar (arr, n);
    cetakArray (arr, n);

}
```

please help me

Comment: Count how many times you call `pindah(&arr[j], &arr[j+1])`.

Comment: Right before `if (trade == false)` add `cetakArray (arr, n);`.

Comment: What do you mean by "into the right sequence number"? Furthermore, it looks like you are using C instead of C++.

Comment: why "in boolean" ? `bool` isnt for counting

Comment: i mean random number to sort number, but I want to see every move this number

Comment: If I understand it right, you could just print the number switches with a `cout`

Comment: BTW, Boolean has only two values: `true` and `false`.  Not very practical for counting.

Comment: BTW, in C++ you should use `for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)` instead of `int i; for (i=0; i<n; i++)`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by "into the right sequence" you mean from small to large, and assuming that you are willing to use C++11, we can easily obtain this with a lambda function. See the following example.

```
  #include <vector>
  #include <algorithm>

  std::vector<int> values({4, 6, 7, 2, 1, 5, 8, 10, 9, 3});

  int number_of_moves = 0;

  std::sort(begin(values), end(values), [&](int lhs, int rhs) 
  {
    if (lhs > rhs) 
      return false; 

    ++number_of_moves;

    std::cout << "I am going to swap " << lhs << " with " << rhs << '\n'; 

    return true; 
  });

  std::cout << "I took me " << number_of_moves << " move(s) to sort the vector\n";
```

Note: it is not clear to me what you mean by "movements in c++ boolean", so I chose to print the numbers that are going to be swapped.

EDIT: based on the comments I guess you want to count the number of movements, so I have added a counter. Note that a `bool` can only be true/false and cannot be used for counting.

Comment: what if the numbers have been determined in random form?

Comment: @Harist, do you mean that the numbers to be sorted are randomly generated?

Comment: Yes, this number already exists but is random. the code only shows the results, I want to see the process swap and the results. How do I add?

Comment: The numbers in the sequence `values` can be randomly generated and it won't affect the answer. I give it another try, do you mean to (1) only sort the first `n` numbers of the sequence, (2) to start sorting and stop after `n` swaps are made (even if the vector is not sorted yet), (3) to count the number of swaps that were required to sort the vector, or (4) something else.